# Automatic (de)initialization on module import

Tags: python, module, import, initialization

In Python, whever a module needs some kind of initialization, in order for it to be done automatically, you can just place the code in the module (with zero indent) to be executed on the first import (right?). Is there any way to do automatic deinitialization when the application closes and the modules get collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way I found, to do this:

```
class __ModuleInitializer:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Module was initialized')

    def __del__(self):
        print('Module was deinitialized')

__module_init = __ModuleInitializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you specifically want to write a `module.init()` method and a `module.stop()` method

I personally HATE things being executed in the module when I import it, at least give me a choice when I want to execute it.

Comment: Even if I don't end up using this very often, it can be useful knowledge to have. PyMunk for example, automatically initializes the library when you import the module. That's a nice thing imo, I always thought that `init` and `quit` functions go against principles like RAII (I'm not specifically talking about Python right now).

Comment: @Paul: But RAII makes little sense in a language with GC because you have little no control over when things decide to finalize. Also modules _are_ scope, they never _leave_ scope - in a sense, their resource _is_ scope - so talking about scope-bound resource management for them makes no sense.

Comment: @Joe I guess I had a poor choice of words. What I meant was, could modules be used as a mechanism to automatically (de)init libraries? Ie., instead of calling `init()`, it is automatically initialized on first import; instead of calling `deinit()`, that happens automatically at program exit.

Comment: They will be shut down when the program ends but if you are that worried do your clean up in an atexit event.